# What do capacitors C0 and Ce do in this RC phase-shift oscillator?

Tags: capacitor, filter, oscillator

[image]

what is the use of the capacitors Ce and Co in the given circuit.

Comment: Co is to prevent DC coupling to the next circuit.  I think Ce is to short AC signals at the transistor's emitter to ground.  But it may also play a part in the oscillator.

Comment: Re is a kind of feedback that will lower the gain and increase linearity. The capacitor causes this Re to be shorted at high frequency. This can increase bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Those capacitances are part of standard [R-C coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-C_coupled) common emitter amplifier.

\$C_O\$ is coupling capacitor which couples the amplified *ac* output to next stage/load but blocks the *DC* bias signal.

\$R_E\$ connected at emitter improve bias stability by providing a negative feedback ([read this answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-C_coupled)). But because of this negative feedback the *ac* signal gain also reduces.

A capacitor \$C_E\$ is connected across \$R_E\$ so that only the *DC* "sees" \$R_E\$ and hence experiences the negative feedback. Where as the *ac* signal is bypassed through \$C_E\$ and the gain is not reduced. This capacitor is called *bypass capacitor*.

Answer (score 1):

The bipolar circuit offers an amplifying function whose gain depends on \$R_C\$ and \$R_E\$. Capacitor \$C_E\$ brings a zero in the transfer function. You can determine the gain of this particular stage by replacing the bipolar transistor by its hybrid-\$\pi\$ model:

[image]

You then obtain a linear circuit from which you solve the transfer function linking \$V_{out}\$ to \$V_{in}\$:

[image]

To solve this circuit swiftly, I would apply the Fast Analytical Circuits Techniques or FACTs described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1119236371). If you do the maths ok, then considering a high gain for the bipolar transistor, you should find:

\$H(s)=H_0\frac{1+\frac{s}{\omega_z}}{1+\frac{s}{\omega_p}}\$ where

\$H_0\approx -\frac{R_C}{R_E}\$

\$\omega_z=\frac{1}{C_ER_E}\$

\$\omega_p=\frac{1}{C_ER_E||(\frac{r_{\pi}}{\beta+1})}\$

and if you plot the dynamic response, you see the phase bumping and peaking at the geometric mean between the zero and the pole:

[image]

As highlighted in the comment, \$R_E\$ provides bias stabilization with respect to temperature (if the transistor's \$\beta\$ grows with temp, the emitter current also and it brings a stabilizing reduction in \$V_{be}\$). If \$C_E\$ is a fairly large value, then it brings the zero at low frequency. \$C_0\$ blocks the dc component for the downstream circuitry as pointed out in the comments.